# Contact form on website not working when we hosted our email on google apps

Tags: email, drupal, google-apps

Hi i am grapich designer but temporary asked working to check this emails problem.

we are using drupal for our website. When we are using google apps as our email server, the contact form on our webpage (which our customer used to use for sending us question) was stop sending emails seems the mail fuction is not working anymore. Is that because we hosted our emails to google apps? Is there anyway that to make work? We need the contact form on our webpage send mail

Comment: What module are you using for your contact form?  Webform?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Webform you can set your email address a few places:

This is where the default Webform email is set:
yoursite.com/admin/config/content/webform

and that default can be overridden in the individual Webform E-mail tab:
yoursite.com/node/1234/webform/emails (1234 is node id of your webform)

Drupal also has a global email address for your site that could be used as the default also, so its worth checking here: yoursite.com/admin/config/system/site-information